What is the difference between simultaneous equations and coupled equations?
I have heard of both terms. Simultaneou eqution more in terms of algebraic equations and coupled equations more interms of PDEs both terms used when dealing with system of equtions. I have also come across the term"simultaneous coupled equations", again for set of PDEs.
What is the difference between simultaneous equations and coupled equations?

Simultanes equation comes with a system of ordinary equations, mostly linear, the have at least  one common solution  this is the simultan.
coupled mean two ore more DE or PDE where the differential of more than one function are in both equations.
